# Find the elements and how (they are / are they) constructed

Tags: word-order

> 1. to find the key elements of these algorithms and how **are they** constructed.
> 2. to find the key elements of these algorithms and how **they are** constructed.

Which of the two sentence above is correct?

Answer (score 1):

These are incomplete sentences, however the *first* one clearly has *wrong word order*: '**are they**' is for an interrogative sentence and not for one with reported speech (find... how *they are*).